# how do get a duplicate of my radio amateur license KP4CSJ

Tags: united-states, license

My  call KP4CSJ (general) I will like to get a copy or duplicate of my license. I lost my and i will like to to hang it in may shack. I am an old timer ham radio over 50 years.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind a watermark that says "Reference Copy", you can go to the [ULS license search](https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/UlsSearch/searchLicense.jsp), find yourself, and click the "Reference Copy" link at the top. This will download a PDF you can print.

If you want a copy without the watermark, see the [instructions from the FCC](https://www.fcc.gov/requesting-duplicate-license-universal-licensing-system-uls):

> 1. Log in to [ULS Online Filing](https://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsEntry/licManager/login.jsp) with your FCC Registration Number (FRN) and Password. 
>      *Note: If you are taken to the My Applications page, click My Licenses to begin the steps below.*
> 2. On the left-hand side of the screen, click Request Duplicates.
> 3. Select the licenses and click Add.
> 4. Click Continue to navigate through the application.
>      Sign your application and click Submit Application.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the FCC web page and locate licensing there input your CALL SIGN and print out a copy of your license. The FCC stopped mailing out these as per the web page.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!